# Convert rows to array

Tags: python

I am new to Python and would like to achieve this.

My data coming from DB is look like this

```
Group Result Freq
1     B      4
1     D      9
1     E      3
2     A      9
2     B      5
2     C      8
2     E      1
3     C      2
3     F      5
4     B      3
4     E      8
```

I want to convert rows to array

to look like this without the Freq

```
Group ResultArray
1     [B,D,E]
2     [A,B,C,E]
3     [C,F]
4     [B,E]
```

I googled and I searched stackoverflow but could find anything similar to follow

I know it must be somewhere in the internet but I searched and could not find anything that help.

so if you know the answer you will save me days of more searching.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using pandas for better data manipulation,

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data) # Load data into dataframe
df.groupby('Group')['Result'].agg(list)
```

Comment: He mentioned Data is coming from DB. In that case we need to ingest this data as a pandas DataFrame

Comment: How to specify to make the array for a single column instead of all columns?

Comment: Updated answer @asmgx